# Trouble installing CouchDB on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, couchdb

I got it off the ubuntu software center and it seems to install ok.

I navigate to

```
http://localhost:5984/
```

and get :

```
:( No data received
```

In terminal I do a

```
curl 127.0.0.1:5984
```

and get

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I restart couchDB with

sudo stop couchdb

sudo start couchdb

Which gets me :

```
couchdb start/running, process 20545
```

Ive turned off my httpd (apache2) just to be sure thats not interfering.

When I do this in terminal (per http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/install/unix.html#first-run):

sudo -i -u couchdb couchdb

I get (among other things) :

```
Failure to start Mochiweb: eaddrinuse
```

Googling that got me this (source : http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Error_messages) :

```
Unavailable Port ...  Solution Edit your /etc/couchdb/couch.ini file and change the Port setting to an available port.
```

So in terminal I look in that directory and all thats there is :

default.d  default.ini  erl_crash.dump  local.d  local.ini  local.ini~

So I google the usage of couchDB configuration files and find that I should be able to configure it by editing local.ini (source : http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/intro.html)

local.ini has in it (among other things)

```
;port = 5984

;bind_address = 127.0.0.1
```

The ; are comments so I uncomment those lines, save, and restart couchdb, and have the same problem.

So I wonder what could be listening on that port so I put this in terminal :

netstat -lnptu

And see only one entry for 127.0.0.1:5984

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5984          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

No PID but I think its connected to this (using top) :

```
29264 couchdb   20   0 58596 3980 1808 S    1  0.1   0:00.03 beam.smp
```

So at this point I have no idea whats wrong or how to fix it, only that it dosent work and I kinda cant believe something so popular (couchDB and Ubuntu 12.04) dont work right out of the box.

What can I do at this point? Jumping out of a window isnt an option because its only a one story building and its cold outside.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I am on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, but perhaps my solution will help.

When I did a `ps -ef | grep couchdb`, I found the following in a process run by couchdb:

```
-couch_ini /etc/couchdb/default.ini /etc/couchdb/local.ini
```

I had already changed local.ini, but that didn't help. When I looked at default.ini, I saw the port and host set there as well, so I removed my changes from local.ini and added them to default.ini. After restarting couchdb, I had success.